# Rooted Galaxy S6 Edge, can I update?

Tags: rooting, updates

I just rooted my **Galaxy S6 Edge** using the *PingPong root* I believe it is called. Just to make sure, it is the root where you take the APK and put it on your phone and click one button and it roots it.

But now I keep getting a popup saying that there is a software update for the phone. How do I update the phone now that it is rooted? If it is not possible, then I have to go without updates, so how do I get rid of the popup??

**Thanks guys**!!

Answer (score 0):

root will not get you banned from the updates you can update your phone normally via kies on PC or on the phone it self if the update is supported to be flashed from the phone ,however I must add that you will probably lose the root access on your phone after the update

Answer (score 0):

Don't update your phone via root otherwise you will lose your previous root permissions and then you will need to re root your device.